# How work URL like http://site.com/#/post/785488/article-title-page?

Tags: javascript, url, prototypejs

I'm working on a site where I have article I can open with a JavaScript only, I've saw this site let to the client to access directly to the last opened article with JavaScript, how does it work?

This is the example:
http://irrland.sonntagskunst.de
http://irrland.sonntagskunst.de/#/post/181111475/man-with-the-dipset-wed-been-getting-paper

I've saw the site uses prototypejs but the site miss the argument (or maybe I haven't found it).
 
Does exists some documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page most likely uses [*Ajax*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to dynamically load content. The content to load is identified by the [*fragment identifier*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), which becomes more common practice with Ajax:

> With the rise of AJAX, some websites use fragment identifiers to emulate the back button behavior of browsers for page changes that do not require a reload, or to emulate subpages. (For example, GMail uses a single URL for almost every interface – mail boxes, individual mails, search results, settings – the fragment is used to make these interfaces directly linkable.)

Comment: Thank you, something like http://www.unfocus.com/projects/historykeeper/ should be useful to access directly to the contents like in http://irrland.sonntagskunst.de